# How backup automated process to my WordPress Sites using code?

Tags: wordpress, backup

I have used the code below on the c-panel WordPress repository and created a backup folder in the public HTML folder.  But not working on  I need to know code issue and where I should customize to get my site automatedly by using code.

```
`function create_backup() {
  // Get the site's URL and name
  $site_url = get_site_url();
  $site_name = get_bloginfo('name');

  // Create a filename for the backup using the site's URL and current date
  $filename = $site_name . '-' . $site_url . '-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.zip';

  // Create a ZIP archive of the site's files
  $zip = new ZipArchive;
  $zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE);
  $zip->addGlob(ABSPATH . '/*');
  $zip->close();

  // Send the ZIP archive to a remote location
  // Replace "example.com" with the URL of your remote location
  $response = wp_remote_post('http://example.com/backups/', array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'timeout' => 45,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking' => true,
    'headers' => array(
      'Content-Type' => 'application/zip'
    ),
    'body' => file_get_contents($filename),
  ));
}`
```

Use the wp_schedule_event() or wp_schedule_single_event() function to schedule the custom function to run at a specific time or interval.

And use this Bloew of this code in functions.php

```
`if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'create_backup_event' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'create_backup_event' );
}

add_action( 'create_backup_event', 'create_backup' );`
```

Please notify me where I need to add my domain name and customization needs!

I have tried this on my Name Cheap Hosting.  But My inquiry is where should I need to create the Back Folder in the Public Html folder or anywhere else?